# update page in our app that get data from the net

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I'm about to release my app (based on the [Cocos2d game engine](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/)) on the iOS App Store, but I'm worried about updating it - I don't have a facility to send my own data to the app outside of the App Store update process.

I'd like to be able to tell my users "hey, an updated version of this app is available!" or to send other similar messages to users that they'll see when they open the app. For example, I'd like to be able to show the user a "there is a new level available for download" message on the app's launch screen.

How could I add a "remote" scene like this, that will only appear when I want it to, outside of the App Store update process? I'm pretty sure that I need a server that I can have my app talk to - is that right? How complicated would it be to set this up? Are there any guides available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 'server side' could be as simple as a piece of text at a given url.

Your client side code will likely want to use [`NSURLConnection`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to query the server.

Answer (score 2):

It's very easy with pictures and text, but DON'T block the user until you've got the response from your server. For example you could write a small python script and run it on Google's cloud service App Engine.

Answer (score 1):

I have a method on my web server that returns JSON with the latest version, and then code in the app as follows:

```
NSNumber *serverVersion = [dict objectForKey:@"version"];

NSNumber *currentVersion = [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleShortVersionString"];

if ([serverVersion intValue] > [currentVersion intValue]) {

   // Out of date
}
```

Which simply checks the version returned in the JSON dictionary against that in the Info.plist. Where I have my comment block you could have your line of code to display your update scene.